# Warning when linking a MinGW program with a MSVC static lib

Tags: c, visual-c++, mingw, static-linking, abi

I have a MinGW64 C++ program, and I need to link it against a MSVC 64bit static C library supplied as an object file (obj)

I converted it to .a using:

```
ar rcs libtest.a test.obj
```

This created the static library without warnings

When I link the program, I get:

> Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file

But the linked program appears to work fine (for how long?)

How can I get rid of this warning? The library is not open source and is supplied by a commercial vendor. I could ask him to compile it with other flags if required.

Answer (score 1):

> I converted it to .a using:

```
ar rcs libtest.a test.obj
```

Actually, this is not *converting* `test.obj` in any way. A static library
(`.a`) is simply an archive of object files plus a table of contents
by which a linker can search it.

Your `ar` command makes a static library containing just `test.obj`.
If you know that your MinGW64 linkage needs `test.obj` there's no
point in putting it in a library all alone. The linker will simply extract `test.obj`
from the library and add it to the linkage, so you might as well
link `test.obj` directly.

If you do that, MinGW64's GNU linker will link it and will emit exactly 
the same warning that you get when you link it from a static library. This 
shows you that what's provoking the warning is *in the object file*, and it's this:-

The PE object file format provides an "abitrary information" section that a compiler conventionally
labels `.drectve` and employs for embedding directives it wants to communicate to the linker,
which will read and obey them - if it can.

MSVC so employs the `.drectve` section and, naturally, writes linker directives there that make
sense of the MS linker, e.g.

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 12.00.31101.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file hw.obj

File Type: COFF OBJECT

   Linker Directives
   -----------------
   /DEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT
   /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES

  Summary

           C .data
          64 .debug$S
          2F .drectve
          12 .text$mn
```

They don't make any sense to the GNU linker, so it warns that the
`.drectve` section is corrupt.

**Can you suppress the warning?**

No, there is no such option.

**Can you get the vendor to head off the warning by compiling `test.obj` for you differently?**

Depending on what the MSVC-generated content of the "corrupt" `.drectve` section is (which
you could discover with `dumpbin`), there may be an MSVC compiler option to suppress
its generation. But more of this later.

**Is the linkage safe?**

Well, the fact that your linker thinks the object file is damaged at all should manage expectations.
MinGW64 come with no promise that you can link MSVC's object files with its own, safely
or at all. MSVC doesn't promise you can link its object files with any others. Windows doesn't regulate the static linkage of
different compilers' object files. In practice, you can link `test.obj` into your otherwise GCC C++ application, because
all the object files are Windows COFF pe-x86-64 object files such as your linker is able to 
link  together, and happily, `test.obj` contains C, not C++,  symbols, so the incompatible 
name-mangling of MS and GCC C++ doesn't thwart it. If the program works, that's as much assurance of 
its safety as you're going to get.

If you really want more assurance - or simply want a binary made from `test.obj` that
you can link to your application without warnings - then try to make a *DLL* out of `test.obj`:

```
    g++ -shared -o test.dll test.obj
```

The same linkage warning is to be expected when you do that one-time step, but if it is otherwise
successful then `test.dll` can be linked to your application with at least the assurance of ABI compatibility,
because it is a DLL.

Which brings us back to the compile-with-different options option. If the vendor will compile
`test.obj` to your requirements, then require the vendor to compile it *as a DLL*. For Windows,
the DLL is the standard unit of ABI compatibility.